# Can you use Flash Local Storage to save data other than text? Images / Sound / Videos

Tags: flash, actionscript

with flash local storage you can save some data like cookies on the client. but is it somehow possible to use it for images as well?

if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save any type of data as long as you convert it to a ByteArray.